# Change Oracle banner without restarting database

Tags: oracle

I am removing the banner for Oracle by commenting out this line in SQLNET.ORA:

```
SEC_USER_AUDIT_ACTION_BANNER=C:\banner.txt
```

Is there any way to make the change take affect without restarting the database?  I've tried `lsnrctl reload`, `lsnrctl start` and `lsnrctl stop`, restarting the windows TNS service, and removing the banner file.

I'm using Oracle 11.2.0.3 on Windows 7.  The real problem is on a Solaris (SPARC) machine, but I don't have any Solaris boxes to test.